# Шлейф от движения объекта

Tags: canvas

Есть простой код движения объекта. Но объект во время движения оставляет шлейф за собой как его убрать?
вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ctx;
var img;
var x = 0;
var y = 40;

 function setup() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('lessonCanvas');
     if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval('draw();', 50);
    img = new Image();
    img.src = 'ufo.png';
                    }
    }

function draw ()
{
 ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
 x+=3;

 if(x>300)
 {
 x=-50;
 y=Math.random()*300;
 }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

в "draw" первой строкой: "ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)"